# Number of solutions of $\tan^2 x - \sec^{10} x +1=0$ in the interval $(0,10)$

Tags: trigonometry

How many solutions of the equation $$\tan^2 x - \sec^{10} x +1=0$$ lie in the interval $(0,10)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**  Since $\tan^2x + 1 = \sec^2x$, 
\begin{align*}
\tan^2x - \sec^{10}x + 1 & = 0\\
\sec^2x - \sec^{10}x & = 0\\
\sec^2x(1 - \sec^8x) & = 0
\end{align*}
Since $\sec^2x \neq 0$, you need to find the solutions of $1 - \sec^8x = 0$ in the interval $(0, 10)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: your equation is equivalent to $$-{\frac { \left( \sin \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2} \left(  \left( 
\cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}+1 \right)  \left(  \left( \cos
 \left( x \right)  \right) ^{4}+1 \right) }{ \left( \cos \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{10}}}
=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$1-\sec^8=0$ if

$\cos ^8 x=1$ that is

$\cos x=\pm 1$ which happens at $x=\pi;\;x=2\pi;\;3\pi$ in the interval $(0,\;10)$